# If statement to include a third colour

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my code below I have it so that each box has a different colour `blue` or `green`.

How can I adjust the code so that I can add a third colour like `grey`?

I got the code below from one of my other SO questions that I asked and could someone also explain what the `%2` means within the `if` statement

**Code:**

```
     <?php $class = 0; ?>
    @foreach ($dealsDB as $deal)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading @if($class%2==0) green @else blue @endif">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>{{ $deal->title }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>{{  $deal->content }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     <?php $class++;?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: which template engine?

Comment: @nogad I have adjusted my tags - Laravel 5 Blade

Answer (score 0):

In your given code, as you only had two options **green** and **blue**, everytime your loop executes, the value of `$class` increased by 1. So using `%2 (Modulo 2)` on `$class` value will always produce either **0** or **1** as result. So you can determine that- if the value is **0** i will use this color or if the value is **1** i will use this color. You used this logic in your if-else condition, nothing more.

Also, you can do it differently. Like, store your colors in an array and then use the index using that logic. Then you don't have to use this nested if-else sequence.

```
<?php 
$class = 0; //loop counter
$colors = array('green', 'blue', 'grey'); //color array to store available colors
$arr_length = count($colors); //count how much option we have
?>
@foreach ($dealsDB as $deal)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading {{$colors[$class % $arr_length]}}">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gift"></i>{{ $deal->title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{  $deal->content }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php $class++;?>
@endforeach
```

See, now you don't even have to think about whether you should Modulo with 2 or 3. If you need any more colors, you just add that to the `$colors` array and don't need to touch the rest of the code.